# How to make a text bigger in the body of a question

Tags: support, asking-questions, formatting

I know if I want to make italic *some text* in the body of my question I should put it between two *'s. Also if I want to make bold **some text**, I should put it between **'s.

How I can make some text bigger? I tried the html code `<font size="7">some text</font>` without success.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? My suspicion is 'you cannot'.

Comment: @JosephWright I just want to make bigger the size of the character 1 (and not []) in [1] to illustrate my question.

Comment: @JosephWright see the http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214573 for what I would like to do. Unfortunately I have to use image which take more resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, since only a subset of HTML tags are supported in the network's visual editor.

The following is taken directly from the [Help Center on Formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting):

> When posting on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange, you can use the **visual editor** (for questions and answers, but not comments), [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), and [some **HTML**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/168244). If you're new to Markdown, you may want to [visit the official Markdown syntax reference page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

"Some **HTML**" here refers to the following tags:

```
<a>              - hyperlink.
<b>              - bold, use as last resort <h1>-<h3>, <em>, and <strong> are 
                   preferred.
<blockquote>     - specifies a section that is quoted from another source.
<code>           - defines a piece of computer code.
<del>            - delete, used to indicate modifications.
<dd>             - describes the item in a <dl> description list.
<dl>             - description list.
<dt>             - title of an item in a <dl> description list.
<em>             - emphasized.
<h1>, <h2>, <h3> - headings.
<i>              - italic.
<img>            - specifies an image tag.
<kbd>            - represents user input (usually keyboard input).
<li>             - list item in an ordered list <ol> or an unordered list <ul>.
<ol>             - ordered list.
<p>              - paragraph.
<pre>            - pre-element displayed in a fixed width font and and 
                   unchanged line breaks.
<s>              - strikethrough.
<sup>            - superscript text appears 1/2 character above the baseline 
                   used for footnotes and other formatting.
<sub>            - subscript appears 1/2 character below the baseline.
<strong>         - defines important text.
<strike>         - strikethrough is deprecated, use <del> instead.
<ul>             - unordered list.
<br>             - line break.
<hr>             - defines a thematic change in the content, usually via a 
                   horizontal line.
```

[some content clipped]

### Important Notes

- HTML tags unlisted above are stripped from the output. They may render in the client preview, but they will always be removed on the server.
- You must enter the tags *exactly as shown*. Any deviation from this list—adding extra spaces, using single quote or no quotes, etc.—means the tag will be stripped.
- We do not (and will not) allow `<table>` tags. Sorry. This is intentional and by design. If you need a quick and dirty "table", use `<pre>` and ASCII layout.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your last comment: You could easily include that in your MWE, compile it and add a picture of it as a whole. The MWE could look like this. I don't think it's much reasonable to try to resemble LaTeX's output by HTML this way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a text~\cite{one,two,three,four}.

\begin{thebibliography}{MM}
\bibitem{one} Item One.
\bibitem[\mbox{\itshape 2}]{two} Item Two.
\bibitem[\mbox{\bfseries 3}]{three} Item Three.
\bibitem[\mbox{\Large 4}]{four} Item Four.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could of course say:

> It renders as
>
> ## [1]
>
> rather than [1]

Comment: How you do it ?

Comment: @Name you can click on the edit link to see the source but it is `> It renders as <h1>[1]</h1>  rather than <h5>[1]</h5>`

Comment: Thanks, in fact the 'edit' links for 'answers' is not available to me. I guess it needs a minimum number of reputation to see it and for me it is not the case. However I can click on 'edit' for questions.